# What characters are widely supported in CSS class names?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, character, classname

As detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names) among other places, the only valid characters in a html/css class name is a-z, A-Z, 0-9, hyphen and underscore, and the first character should be a letter. But in practice, what characters are in fact supported by most browsers? More specifically, I wonder what browsers properly understands a slash (/) in a class name, and what browsers support class names starting with a number.

I'm primarily interested in getting an answer for html rather than xhtml, in case there is a difference.

Thank you.

Comment: Didn't tou just say, "a-z, A=Z, 0-9, =, _"?

Comment: Those are the valid characters, but in practice other characters are also supported at least by certain browsers. I wonder what characters can reliably be used except for the valid ones (if any).

Comment: Why not just open up Notepad and give it a test...

Comment: Why would you even consider using invalid class names?

Comment: Sometimes using a number in the beginning or a slash or other character is simply the most natural way to name the class, so e.g adding letters at the beginning just for the sake of it can hurt readability of the markup a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that class names are defined by HTML, not CSS. HTML4 [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-class) the `class` attribute is a `cdata-list`, which is space-separated tokens. So a single classname token can contain any character except the whitespace characters.

> I wonder what browsers properly understands a slash (/) in a class name, and what browsers support class names starting with a number.

To refer to such names in a CSS class selector you would need to use an escape. eg.:

```
<div class="1blah/bläh">
```

is matched by:

```
.\31 blah\2F bläh { ... }
```

This is supported by **all current browsers**. It wasn't supported by IE5, but that's thankfully no longer a concern. (If you had concerns about character encoding mismatches, you might prefer to encode the `ä` as `\E4`, but that's not a limitation of CSS as such.)

If you're asking which browsers will let you get away with the invalid selector

```
.1blah/bläh
```

Then, well, who cares really? Just use the valid one.

Comment: +1 and I would love to give you another one for the last line alone!

Comment: Valid class names *are* defined by CSS. But the ones that are also valid in HTML is just a subset of those. Note that CSS is a style sheet language that can be used for any structured language and not just HTML.

Comment: Thank you bobince, that solves the problem for me! I originally named this question "What characters are widely supported in HTML class names?" but someone changed "HTML" to "CSS". The important thing for me in this case is to make the HTML readable without risking problems, so this helps a lot. IE5 breaking might not be an issue in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see. [And yeah, there's essentially no difference in XHTML, FWIW.]

Comment: so `class="a1<2"` is valid ?

Comment: @Royi: no, but `class="a1&lt;2"` is.

Comment: @bobince So I don't understand what is `cdata-list` it says anything but whitespaces. So I can't understand why my example is not valid...

Comment: `a1<2` is a valid CSS class name and a valid value for the HTML attribute `class`. However in HTML if you want to include a literal `<` character in markup you have to spell it as `&lt;`. If you then read the `className` of the element with that attribute you will see it is `a1<2`.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/syndata.html

If you look at the grammar you understand that identifiers are defined as

```
ident       {nmstart}{nmchar}*
nmstart     [a-zA-Z]|{nonascii}|{escape}
nmchar      [a-z0-9-]|{nonascii}|{escape}
nonascii    [^\0-\177]
unicode     \\[0-9a-f]{1,6}[ \n\r\t\f]?
```

so here's your answer..

(this is for CSS2)

Comment: That does not explain what characters or sequences are actually supported. Is `.foo\ bar`, `.\/` or `.\1234` supported?

Answer (score 1):

Unicode works http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/unicode_for_css_class_names

Answer (score -1):

/ and other symbols are used as **selectors** (especially in CSS3) so can not be used in class names. The supported characters are the ones you already said.